# Compute the compression ratio for Huffman algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, compression, huffman-code, lossless-compression

I used this code [HuffmanCode](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/huffman-decoding/)to compress this text

> AndwhenthishappenswhenweallowfreedomringwhenweletitringfromeveryvillageandeveryhamletfromeverystateandeverycitywewillbeabletospeedupthatdaywhenallofGod'schildrenblackmenandwhitemenJewsandGentilesProtestantsandCatholicswillbeabletojoinhandsandsinginthewordsoftheoldNegrospiritual

When I save this text in txt file, the size of the file was 1K (original file). Then, I saved the output of the Huffman algorithm that represent the compressed data in another txt file(I copied the output from the command prompt and then pasted it into a file), I found the size of encoded data in the file was 3K!

This is the compressed data that should be used in  `decode_file()` to get on the original data.

> 0110001111100101111110001100111010100001011100100001110111000111000110011100010111110001100111011111100110110111011010011111111100001110010001010100111101001101111110110000111110001100111011111100101110010100111101000110111111011000011110000110100111101100110011100001100000110011011110111011110111000010011011110010110011001110000110000000011101111101101110010101111000011010011110110011001110000110000000101010110110101001101111001011001100111000011000000000110111101000000111111001111101111011101111001010011011100101011100101001000010110001100100010101100001100011010000111011010010111010000011111000110011101101101110110100111100000010001000101011000100010000011000101111011010100111001110110010101111010000110110011111110110011101101111001011111100010111101010011110110011100110010110011111001011011110010100001001001110101001111011100001000001011001101001010100001010101101111010100010110111100101000010101101101000010100101101110000110010111110111101110110110111001010001101110111001010111000110110100100011010110011001000111111001101000111011110010100100110111011110010101101001001111110110000011111101010000110011111010000110101001001001111001010000110001001011010101100100100110000001101000010110001011100110111101001100001101101101101

How do I deal with the compressed data correctly in order to get a size smaller than the original file size? to compute the

```
CR = original data / compressed data
```

Because I am trying to calculate the compression ratio, but it is illogical that the size of the compressed data is greater than the size of the original data.
Any advice,please?

**Update**:

To compute the compression ratio:

1. The size of input:
   if the input was:

```c
    int input[]={1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,2};
    int inputsize = 13 * sizeof(int);
```

2. The size of output:

```
    symbol :1 freq : 3
    symbol :2 freq : 4
    symbol :3 freq : 3 
    symbol :4 freq : 2 
    symbol :5 freq : 1 
    (1 * 3) + (2 * 4) + (3 * 4) + (4 * 2)+(5*1)
    3+ 8 + 12 + 8 + 5 = 36 bits/8 = ~5 bytes.
    int outputsize = 5;
```

3. `CRatio = inputsize /outputsize`

Would this method be correct?

Comment: Is the "encoded data" that you copied a text string consisting of the literal characters `0` and `1`?

Comment: Yes, I added the compressed data to my question. So how can I get on the size of encoded data?

Comment: Compress into raw bytes. BTW if you use 0 and 1 characters, it is guaranteed that Huffman compression won't do any actual compression, because at least one bit (and usually more) is used for each symbol.

Comment: A byte contains 8 bits. You seem to be converting each bit to its own byte so that you can display it. If you divide the length of your output by 8 (and round up), that is how many actual bytes result from encoding. You compressed from 278 bytes to 1246 bits, which will fit in 156 bytes.

Comment: Do you understand that that's an "encoding" of the encoded data? You mapped arbitrary 8-bit characters to a variable number of only-0-and-1 8-bit characters, so of course the file size is bigger. The actual, "raw" compressed data won't isn't text that you can copy-paste.

Comment: Please, what do you suggest I do in order to get on the correct size of the encoded data? Can you explain more, please?

Comment: Did you read my comment?

Comment: @paddy, yes, now if I understand correctly, I compute the compression ratio in this way, is this correct? int sizeoriginalinput = str.size();
float Compratio = ((float)(nbEle))/(encodedString.size()/8);

Comment: _Sort of_ correct. `encodedString.size()` is an integer value, so dividing that by 8 will truncate. It's unclear whether you need the exact bit count, or the bit count rounded to the minimum number of bytes that will hold it. You're actually doing neither. Option A (exact bits -- scale the original size to bits): `float ratio = (float)(origSize * 8) / encodedSize;`. Option B (round encoded bits to nearest whole byte): `float ratio = (float)origSize / ((encodedSize + 7) / 8);`

Comment: Thanks a lot @paddy. I have another question please, if I use int array as input to the algorithm and compute the ratio in this way, is this correct?                                         int input[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,3,1};                                                                                                 string encodedSize;
int nbEle = sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0]); 
float Compratio = (float)(nbEle * sizeof(int)) / ((encodedSize.size() + 7) / 8) ;

Comment: If you only need the size, you don't actually need to form the whole compressed form, you can add up the code lengths corresponding to the input symbols (and then do that division by 8, rounded up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is 278 characters, and your output is 1246 bits. If you assume each character takes eight bits, then you compressed the input to 56% of its original size. Seems about right. (Though see note below.)

If you are measuring your output as one byte for each 0 and each 1, then indeed it will appear to have expanded. But only because you are storing the result incorrectly. You need to store one bit per bit (eight bits in each byte), not one bit per byte.

Though the output length looks about right for Huffman coding, it does not have everything a decoder will need to decode the bits. To get a real measure of the compression, you need to include a description of the Huffman code as well as the encoded data. That could take on the order of another 300 bits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
if I compute the compression ratio as I did in update question is that correct?

Comment: Your input size depends on how it is represented. Those integers don't need four bytes each. If that's what your integers are usually like, then you could code them in one byte each. Or even three bits each.

Comment: The output size is computed correctly, except per my answer, you need to add a representation of the Huffman code to the output.

Comment: sorry one more thing i couldn't understand this sentence "you need to add a representation of the Huffman code to the output" how can do that ?

Comment: There are many ways. I recommend first that you write decoder for your Huffman codes. You will discover what information you need to decode.